# WPF Pie Charts With Overlays

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit

Do you know of an updated version (for wpf toolkit v 4) of Pete Browns following sample?

http://10rem.net/blog/2009/01/09/dazzling-silverlight-toolkit-pie-charts-with-overlays#commentform

or else could you please let me know how to do such a template and apply it to a chart (pie or what ever). I am looking for a way to start making good templates for wpf toolkit charts. Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look to Microsoft Chart, i think you can quite easilly make your own overlays.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart

Comment: hi ykatchou, thanks for the reply. But ms charts is not what I am looking for. Performance of ms charts in a wpf environment via windows forms host is pathetically slow. I am looking for a free wpf version of a charting library. I think wpf toolkit charts are the only option which I can think of enhancing.

Answer (score 0):

*[amCharts](http://wpf.amcharts.com)* has nice charts, also including a 2D-/3D-pieChart.

May be worth a look, it is also free for commercial use as linkware (you have a hyperlink on the upper-left corner of the control); we are currently using it, possibly upgrading to full version if our product manager does not want the link anymore. :p

Cheers, Roland